# BuddyPress - add/remove friends hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, buddypress

I have created `WordPress` plugin and I am facing the issue while adding/removing friends via `WordPress` plugin hooks.

Lets considered an example: (User A & B)

A have sent a friends request to B and B accepted the request and vise versa.

So I have called a `BuddyPress` hooks `friends_friendship_accepted` when request getting accepted and called `friends_friendship_deleted` when user cancelled the friend request.

But both the hooks not behaving properly. Please let me know if anyone aware with friends hooks of `BuddyPress`.

I have already seen the below link:
https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/action-reference/friends/

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.